# If Z is a standard normal random variable, then so is −Z?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Since the standard normal random variable, x,  has a symmetric distribution, wouldn't that mean that -x would also have one? I saw this question on my study guide and thought it was interesting.

Comment: What is $fZ$? ${}$

Comment: @copper.hat: It's possible OP intended to begin the title with "If $Z$ is a standard normal..."

Comment: @BrianTung :-).

Comment: @BrianTung Your right. I edited the question

Comment: If $Z$ is _any_ normal random variable, then so is $-Z$ a normal random variable (with the same variance as $Z$, and mean equal to the negative of the mean of $Z$).  More generally, $aZ+b$ a normal random with mean $a\mu_Z+b$ and variance $a^2 \sigma_Z^2$.

Comment: Use the fact that $P[Z \le x]= \Phi(x)$ and that $\Phi(-x) = 1- \Phi(x)$.